# Accurate cumulative sum for floats in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, floating-point, python-itertools

Given a list of floats in Python, what is the most accurate way to produce the accumulated sums of that list?

By *accurate* I mean robust against rounding errors.

In particular I am trying to understand if I should use `list(itertools.accumulate(my_list))` or calculate this list in pairs by using `math.fsum()`?

Numpy is not an option.

Is `itertools.accumulate(my_list)` using an accurate sum function internally for floats like `math.fsum()` or not?

What are their differences in this case?

If possible, can `math.fsum` be specified as the addition function in `itertools.accumulate` and does that make sense?

Comment: What do you mean by accurate

Comment: it's specified in parenthesis, updated the first line. In the sense more robust against rounding errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is `itertools.accumulate(my_list)` using an accurate sum function internally for floats like `math.fsum()` or not?

No, `PyNumber_Add` is used in the [itertools source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ed70a344b5fbddea85726ebc1964ee0cfdef9c40/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L3550). `PyNumber_Add` is the [standard addition, like `x + y`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/number.html#c.PyNumber_Add) in python

> If possible, can `math.fsum` specified in `itertools.accumulate` as the addition function to be used?

Yes, you can specify it with the [optional `func` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
import itertools
import math

l = [.1, .2, .3, .4, .5]

list(itertools.accumulate(l, lambda x, y: math.fsum([x, y])))
```

> Does that make sense?

No, as [stated in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fsum), `math.fsum`

> avoids loss of precision by tracking multiple intermediate partial sums

So using it makes only sense for more than two floats at once:

```
>>> import math
>>> .1 + .2 + .3 == math.fsum([.1, .2, .3])
False
>>> .1 + .2  == math.fsum([.1, .2])
True
```

You most likley want something like this:

```
>>> import math
>>> 
>>> l = [.1, .2, .3, .4, .5]
>>> [math.fsum(l[:i+1]) for i in range(len(l))]
[0.1, 0.30000000000000004, 0.6, 1.0, 1.5]
```